# How to iterate over json with root node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a json with root node:

```html
{
"comments":
  [
    {"id":1,"author_name":null,"comment_text":null,"url":"http://localhost:3000/comments/1.json"}
  ]
}
```

and I want to go through each object.
This is what i try:

```html
 var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function(comment,index){
            // do something over each object
            );
        });
```

But it is not working:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.comments.map is not a function
```

Comment: How did you define a variable `this.props` ?

Comment: @TaoP.R., forgot to mention, this is actually React.

Comment: Map is for arrays not objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over it with a for loop like this:

```
data = {
    "comments": [
        {   
            "id": 1,
            "author_name": null,
            "comment_text": null,
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/comments/1.json"
        }, { 
            "id": 2,
            "author_name": null,
            "comment_text": null,
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/comments/2.json"
        }
    ]
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.comments.length; i++) {
    var comment = data.comments[i];

    // do something with the comment
    // console.log(comment.id);
    // console.log(comment.url);
}
```

Or if you want to get all comment authors for example, you could do this:

```
var authors = data.comments.map(function(comment) {
    return comment.author_name;
});
```